# How to fetch data from Realm object server to recycler view adapter in android studio

Tags: android, realm, android-recyclerview, realm-mobile-platform

How can I fetch data from a Realm object server to a recycler View adapter in Android Studio? I also want to update data for multiple devices at a time?

Comment: See https://github.com/realm/my-first-realm-app and út also has an accompanying tutorial somewhere

Comment: Hi @rahis, it would help if you posted your code that you have tried so far. See [ask] and [mcve] for more info, and welcome to SO by the way!